# Soll unsere Community am Winter-Bash teilnehmen?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

**UPDATE 2012-11-28:**

Alea iacta: I've sent the

```
WE OPT IN
```

email.

---

We moderators were contacted by a StackExchange community moderator about this:

> Last year, on our Gaming site, we hosted an event called Hat Dash, where users earned "hats" for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions would trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar could then "wear".
>
> For example, editing a post would yield an editor-themed hat (fedora with pen) to the editor.
>
> This year, we're expanding the promotion to all sites which choose to participate, and redesigning the hat selection to be more appropriate to the entire network (no severed Wampa heads). Some of it is holiday-themed, some of it is a bit silly, and all of it is (hopefully) fun!
>
> This event will run **from 19 December 2012 to 4 January 2013**. Users will be able to see their entire hat collection on http://winterba.sh. That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.
>
> Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an "I hate hats" option available, just as we had on Gaming last year.
>
> The only visual change to the site itself will be the presence of the hats and the "I hate hats" button in the footer.
>
> All responses will need to be in **by 28 November 2012**. Sites that haven’t responded by then will be considered to have "opted out" from the event.

[image: Winter Bash]

I propose we do a little voting thing. If votes are 50:50, I'll decide. (I am PRO) ;-).

Comment: Mögen Sie hats? :D Ich mag Hüte!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it's a good idea and sounds fun!

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think we need this.

Comment: Ich glaube wir brauchen Fragen, Fragen und (neue) Besucher. Da so wenig los ist werden Hausmeisterdienste schon aus Langeweile durchgeführt. Die Aktion schadet sicher nicht, also wer Spaß dran hat - bitte. Die Sabotagegruppe trifft sich am 18. Dez. und beseitigt alle Fehler vorab, löscht chatty Kommentare und überlegt sich bessere Tags. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Hu, 28.11. - Last chance!

I think it sounds fun, and it doesn't hurt, 'cause you can disable the hats ;).